# Proving $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n)\leqslant E(X)\leqslant 1+\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

> Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},\mathbb{P})$ a probability space and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ a random variable. Prove:
>
> $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n)\leqslant E(X)\leqslant 1+\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n)$$

I have an intuition for the sums when $X$ is discrete but I do not know how to prove the statement. I have no idea. I need to get a grip on how to tackle problems with probability measure.

**Question**:

Can someone help me prove the inequalities?

Thanks in advance!p

Comment: Non-negative r.v.?

Comment: Make a picture with e.g. the probability space being $[0,1]$ and an integrable nonnegative function $f$ instead of $X$. The estimate then says $\sum_{n \ge 1} \lambda(f \ge n) \le \int_{[0,1]} f(x) dx \le  1 + \sum_{n \ge 1} \lambda(f \ge n) $, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Can you see from the picture why this is true?

Comment: Please, read the comments and modify your question accordingly. You need to assume $X\geq 0$, otherwise the inequality you want to prove is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am assuming $X$ is non-negative, i.e., $X\colon \Omega\to [0,\infty)$. Otherwise, the result you aim to prove is false.*

**Hint:** You can artificially "discretize" the [integral defining expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case_2) as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq x\} dx
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq x\} dx \tag{1}
$$
and then use the easy bounds
$$
\mathbb{P}\{ X\geq n+1\} \leq \int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq x\} dx\leq \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq n\} \tag{2}
$$

Comment: I am supposed to integrate with respect to the measure $\mathbb{P}$. $E(X)=\int_{\Omega} Xd\mathbb{P}$

Comment: This is an equivalent characterization of the expected value. Click on the link for more details. @PedroGomes.

Comment: How should I compute the integral of a measure?

Comment: I am not understanding how you got the bounds.

Comment: @PedroGomes Which (in)equality  do you not understand. (1), (2)?

Comment: The second one, thanks for your support.

Comment: @PedroGomes The function $x\mapsto \mathbb{P}\{X\geq x\}$ is non-decreasing (do you agree? If $x<y$, $\mathbb{P}\{X\geq y\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{X\geq x\}$). Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}\{ X\geq n+1\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq x\} \leq \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq n\} \qquad \forall x\in[n,n+1]$$ and, integrating, $$\int_n^{n+1}  \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq n+1\} dx \leq \int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq x\} dx\leq \int_n^{n+1}  \mathbb{P}\{ X\geq n\} dx$$

Comment: How are you integrating $\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: Why does not the set function change?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I write, as standard, $\mathbb{P}\{X \in S\} = \mathbb{P}( X^{-1}(S) )$ for a set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. What exactly is the issue you have? @PedroGomes

Comment: @PedroGomes Clement is not integrating $\mathbb P$. They are integrating a particular function of $x$. That function is $g(x)=\mathbb P(X\ge x)$. This is like the cdf of $X$, but with $\ge$ in place of $\le$.

Answer (score 3):

This is true only if $X$ is non-negative.

Let $Y = \lfloor X \rfloor$ (floor function, integer part). Then $Y \le  X < Y+1$ and

$$ E[Y] \le E[X] < 1+E[Y] \tag1$$

Also, if $Y$ is a discrete non-negative random variable, [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formula_for_non-negative_random_variables) $$ E[Y] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \mathbb{P}(Y\geqslant n)\tag2$$

Further, for any integer $n\ge 1$, $X \ge n \iff  Y \ge n$

Then 
$$
\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n)\leqslant E(X) <1+\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X\geqslant n) \tag3$$

which is a little stronger than the original inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y=\lfloor X\rfloor$. Obviously, $EY\le EX$, because $0\le Y\le X$ always. Furthermore,
$$
E[Y]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nP(Y=n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nP(n\le X< n+1)
$$
Let $p_n=P(n\le X<n+1)$. We will rearrange the summation as follows:
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccl}
\sum_n np_n= & p_1&+&p_2&+&p_3&+&\dots &+&p_n&+\dots &= &P(X\ge 1)& +
 \\& &&p_2&+&p_3&+&\dots &+&p_n&+\dots & &P(X\ge 2)& +
 \\& &&&&p_3&+&\dots &+&p_n&+\dots &&P(X\ge 3)& +
 \\& &&&& &&\ddots&&&\vdots &&\vdots
\\\\&&&&&&&&&&&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n)
\end{array}
Therefore, we see that
$$
E[X]\ge E[Y]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty np_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n).
$$
For the other inequality, let $Z=\lceil Z\rceil$, and use $EX\le EZ$.