# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{X\ge n\}\le EX\le 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{X\ge n\}$.

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ be a non negative random variable. Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{X\ge n\}\le EX\le 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{X\ge n\}.$$
Now, the thing is I need this to prove the next part of the question, which is $EX=\int_0^\infty P\{X\ge x\}\lambda(dx)$, so I am not supposed to use this definition for proving the above inequality. I have managed to prove the following by breaking up the integrals but, I'm stuck after it.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}xf(x)\lambda(dx)\le EX\le1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}xf(x)\lambda(dx)$$
Somehow proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}xf(x)\lambda(dx)=P\{X\ge n\}$ should solve my issue but I don't think it to be true. Perhaps there is a different approach? Help would be great, please.

*NOTE. There are similar questions on the site but with answers I'm unable to completely understand or with some modifications like X only takes integral values etc.*

Comment: For clarity, can you state your definition of EX? Is if $ \int x \, dx$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Sure. The current definitions I'm using are: $\int_\Omega X(\omega)P(d\omega),\int_\mathbb{R}xP_X(dx),\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x)dx$ and all integrals are wrt to $\lambda$ so I sometimes write it like $\lambda(dx)$

Comment: Hint: $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x \leq 1 + \lfloor x \rfloor$. Now review the question which modifies $X$ to integral values to motivate how to proceed.

Comment: @CalvinLin I can't figure how to. Sorry, but could you elaborate more on this?

Comment: there are infinitely many questions about this topic, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173311/let-x-be-a-non-negative-random-variable-and-a-i-be-the-event-that-x-is-be?noredirect=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3892170/expected-value-inequality-for-non-negative-random-variable?noredirect=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3171180/proving-sum-limitsn-1-infty-mathbbpx-geqslant-n-leqslant-ex-leqsla?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Masacroso the first one does, thank you! somehow i got couldn't find it earlier.